# How to prevent JQuery elements interfering with each other

Tags: jquery, validation

I am having trouble getting these two elements to work at the same time on the page. They work separately, but not together. Any help?

First Element:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="compressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('slideshow').style.display='none';
$('wrapper2').style.display='block';
var slideshow=new TINY.slideshow("slideshow");
window.onload=function(){
    slideshow.auto=false;
    slideshow.speed=5;
    slideshow.info="information";
    slideshow.thumbs="slider";
    slideshow.left="slideleft";
    slideshow.right="slideright";
    slideshow.scrollSpeed=4;
    slideshow.spacing=5;
    slideshow.active="#fff";
    slideshow.init("slideshow","image");
    }
</script>
```

Second Element:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en', style : google.loader.themes.SHINY});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('012677673255316824096:sean13fvlei');
    customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
    var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
    options.setSearchFormRoot('cse-search-form');
    customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
  }, true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#hidr").click(function () {
     $("#cse").hide("slow", function () {
      // use callee so don't have to name the function
       $(this).hide("fast"); 
      });
   });
    $("#cse-search-form").click(function () {
      $("#cse").show(2000);
    });
</script>
```

Compressed.js File:

```
var TINY = {};

 function $(i) {
  return document.getElementById(i)
  }
      function $$(e, p) {
      p = p || document;
   return p.getElementsByTagName(e)
}
TINY.slideshow = function (n) {
   this.infoSpeed = this.imgSpeed = this.speed = 1;
   this.thumbOpacity = this.navHover = 100;
   this.navOpacity = 25;
   this.scrollSpeed = 5;
   this.letterbox = '#000';
   this.n = n;
   this.c = 0;
   this.a = []
   };
TINY.slideshow.prototype = {
       init: function (s, z, b, f, q) {
        s = $(s);
        var m = $$('li', s),
            i = 0,
            w = 0;
        this.l = m.length;
        this.q = $(q);
        this.f = $(z);
        this.r = $(this.info);
        this.o = parseInt(TINY.style.val(z, 'width'));
       if (this.thumbs) {
            var u = $(this.left),
                r = $(this.right);
            u.onmouseover = new Function('TINY.scroll.init("' + this.thumbs + '",-1,' + this.scrollSpeed + ')');
            u.onmouseout = r.onmouseout = new Function('TINY.scroll.cl("' + this.thumbs + '")');
            r.onmouseover = new Function('TINY.scroll.init("' + this.thumbs + '",1,' + this.scrollSpeed + ')');
            this.p = $(this.thumbs)
        }
        for (i; i < this.l; i++) {
            this.a[i] = {};
            var h = m[i],
                a = this.a[i];
            a.t = $$('h3', h)[0].innerHTML;
            a.d = $$('p', h)[0].innerHTML;
            a.l = $$('a', h)[0] ? $$('a', h)[0].href : '';
            a.p = $$('span', h)[0].innerHTML;
           if (this.thumbs) {
               var g = $$('img', h)[0];
               this.p.appendChild(g);
            w += parseInt(g.offsetWidth);
            if (i != this.l - 1) {
                g.style.marginRight = this.spacing + 'px';
                w += this.spacing
            }
            this.p.style.width = w + 'px';
            g.style.opacity = this.thumbOpacity / 100;
            g.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + this.thumbOpacity + ')';
            g.onmouseover = new Function('TINY.alpha.set(this,100,5)');
            g.onmouseout = new Function('TINY.alpha.set(this,' + this.thumbOpacity + ',5)');
            g.onclick = new Function(this.n + '.pr(' + i + ',1)')
        }
    }
    if (b && f) {
        b = $(b);
        f = $(f);
        b.style.opacity = f.style.opacity = this.navOpacity / 100;
        b.style.filter = f.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + this.navOpacity + ')';
        b.onmouseover = f.onmouseover = new Function('TINY.alpha.set(this,' + this.navHover + ',5)');
        b.onmouseout = f.onmouseout = new Function('TINY.alpha.set(this,' + this.navOpacity + ',5)');
        b.onclick = new Function(this.n + '.mv(-1,1)');
        f.onclick = new Function(this.n + '.mv(1,1)')
    }
    this.auto ? this.is(0, 0) : this.is(0, 1)
},
mv: function (d, c) {
    var t = this.c + d;
    this.c = t = t < 0 ? this.l - 1 : t > this.l - 1 ? 0 : t;
    this.pr(t, c)
},
pr: function (t, c) {
    clearTimeout(this.lt);
    if (c) {
        clearTimeout(this.at)
    }
    this.c = t;
    this.is(t, c)
},
is: function (s, c) {
    if (this.info) {
        TINY.height.set(this.r, 1, this.infoSpeed / 2, -1)
    }
    var i = new Image();
    i.style.opacity = 0;
    i.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';
    this.i = i;
    i.onload = new Function(this.n + '.le(' + s + ',' + c + ')');
    i.src = this.a[s].p;
    if (this.thumbs) {
        var a = $$('img', this.p),
            l = a.length,
            x = 0;
        for (x; x < l; x++) {
            a[x].style.borderColor = x != s ? '' : this.active
        }
    }
},
le: function (s, c) {
    this.f.appendChild(this.i);
    var w = this.o - parseInt(this.i.offsetWidth);
    if (w > 0) {
        var l = Math.floor(w / 2);
        this.i.style.borderLeft = l + 'px solid ' + this.letterbox;
        this.i.style.borderRight = (w - l) + 'px solid ' + this.letterbox
    }
    TINY.alpha.set(this.i, 100, this.imgSpeed);
    var n = new Function(this.n + '.nf(' + s + ')');
    this.lt = setTimeout(n, this.imgSpeed * 100);
    if (!c) {
        this.at = setTimeout(new Function(this.n + '.mv(1,0)'), this.speed * 1000)
    }
    if (this.a[s].l != '') {
        this.q.onclick = new Function('window.location="' + this.a[s].l + '"');
        this.q.onmouseover = new Function('this.className="' + this.link + '"');
        this.q.onmouseout = new Function('this.className=""');
        this.q.style.cursor = 'pointer'
    } else {
        this.q.onclick = this.q.onmouseover = null;
        this.q.style.cursor = 'default'
    }
    var m = $$('img', this.f);
    if (m.length > 2) {
        this.f.removeChild(m[0])
    }
 },
 nf: function (s) {
    if (this.info) {
        s = this.a[s];
        $$('h3', this.r)[0].innerHTML = s.t;
        $$('p', this.r)[0].innerHTML = s.d;
        this.r.style.height = 'auto';
        var h = parseInt(this.r.offsetHeight);
        this.r.style.height = 0;
        TINY.height.set(this.r, h, this.infoSpeed, 0)
    }
 }
};
TINY.scroll = function () {
   return {
     init: function (e, d, s) {
        e = typeof e == 'object' ? e : $(e);
        var p = e.style.left || TINY.style.val(e, 'left');
        e.style.left = p;
        var l = d == 1 ? parseInt(e.offsetWidth) - parseInt(e.parentNode.offsetWidth) : 0;
        e.si = setInterval(function () {
            TINY.scroll.mv(e, l, d, s)
        }, 20)
    },
    mv: function (e, l, d, s) {
        var c = parseInt(e.style.left);
        if (c == l) {
            TINY.scroll.cl(e)
        } else {
            var i = Math.abs(l + c);
            i = i < s ? i : s;
            var n = c - i * d;
            e.style.left = n + 'px'
        }
    },
    cl: function (e) {
        e = typeof e == 'object' ? e : $(e);
        clearInterval(e.si)
    }
  }
}();
TINY.height = function () {
   return {
    set: function (e, h, s, d) {
        e = typeof e == 'object' ? e : $(e);
        var oh = e.offsetHeight,
            ho = e.style.height || TINY.style.val(e, 'height');
        ho = oh - parseInt(ho);
        var hd = oh - ho > h ? -1 : 1;
        clearInterval(e.si);
        e.si = setInterval(function () {
            TINY.height.tw(e, h, ho, hd, s)
        }, 20)
    },
    tw: function (e, h, ho, hd, s) {
        var oh = e.offsetHeight - ho;
        if (oh == h) {
            clearInterval(e.si)
        } else {
            if (oh != h) {
                e.style.height = oh + (Math.ceil(Math.abs(h - oh) / s) * hd) + 'px'
            }
        }
    }
}
}();
TINY.alpha = function () {
   return {
    set: function (e, a, s) {
        e = typeof e == 'object' ? e : $(e);
        var o = e.style.opacity || TINY.style.val(e, 'opacity'),
            d = a > o * 100 ? 1 : -1;
        e.style.opacity = o;
        clearInterval(e.ai);
        e.ai = setInterval(function () {
            TINY.alpha.tw(e, a, d, s)
        }, 20)
    },
    tw: function (e, a, d, s) {
        var o = Math.round(e.style.opacity * 100);
        if (o == a) {
            clearInterval(e.ai)
        } else {
            var n = o + Math.ceil(Math.abs(a - o) / s) * d;
            e.style.opacity = n / 100;
            e.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + n + ')'
            }
        }
    }
}();
TINY.style = function () {
    return {
        val: function (e, p) {
            e = typeof e == 'object' ? e : $(e);
            return e.currentStyle ? e.currentStyle[p] : document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(e, null).getPropertyValue(p)
        }
    }
}();
```

Comment: That's a rather large amount of code to look at. Could you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: You're missing two key points of information in your question:  1) What's it SUPPOSED to do?, and 2) What exactly is it doing NOW?  Things like 'it works', or 'it doesn't work' are hard to understand especially with the amount of code you've pasted in here.  Hope this helps you refine your question.

Comment: if i have "var m =" with the same in both would that effect the out come, or make them not work on the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('slideshow').style.display='none';
$('wrapper2').style.display='block';
```

Will not work, use:

```
$('slideshow').css("display", "none");
$('wrapper2').css("display", "block");
```

or

```
$('slideshow')[0].style.display='none';
$('wrapper2')[0].style.display='block';
```

Also I do not see your slideshow creating any elements with the tag names `<slideshow>` or `<wrapper2>`.

Comment: Both elements work correctly, I just can't get them both to work on the page